# I want to change the value of a string

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have a string that has value Grade 1.I want to change it to grade_1

here is my code.

```
         $gradeselection="Grade 1";          //it is getting value from a select box .this is just for understanding.
```

I have used preg_replace but not getting the solution.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just change it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of preg_replace you can use str_replace 
**try this one**

```
echo str_replace("Grade 1","grade_1",$gradeselection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
strtolower(str_replace(" ","_","Grade 1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$gradeselection="Grade 1";

echo strtolower(str_replace(" ","_", $gradeselection));
// str_replace replace _ with space and than convert it into lower case
```